Cannot access 'androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity' when I enable ProGuard in kotlin
I have a code like this in my application project
I try to connect this library to my application project below
myActivity.start(
                    ...
                )

but I get this error ->
Cannot access 'androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity' which is a supertype of 'myActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

hear is codes from sdk project
myActivity
class myActivity : BaseActivity() {

    companion object {
       
     
        fun start(...) {
           ...
        }
    }
}

BaseActivity
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BaseActivityUtils {
    companion object {
        fun optionalExit(baseActivityUtils: BaseActivityUtils?) {
           ...
        }
    }


    override fun exit() {
        finish()
    }
} 

I declared rules in my proguard like this
-keep class myActivity { *; }
-keepclassmembers class myActivity {
    public static ** Companion;
}
-keepclassmembers class myActivity$Companion {
    <methods>;
}
-keep class com.myProject.BaseActivity { *; }
-keep interface com.myProject.BaseActivityUtils

When I go AppCompatActivity which is extends BaseActivity I can't go inside AppCompatActivity but I can go if I want to go BaseActivityUtils. I couldn't understand what it is the problem ? is anybody encounter this error ? or this error is relevant with ProGuard or not ? How can I solve this problem ? should I add AppCompatActivity to my ProGuard ? I couldn't see anything to relevant this

What happens if you remove proguard usage? If it works after that then you know its something with proguard

yes of course when I isMinifyEnabled true to false it works very well so How can I solve it ?

could you try this please:
-keep class androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity { *; }

no it doesn't work unfortunately
